# What will be the regular expression for parsing all words except last one?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match the whole string except the last word. i.e. for

```
This is my house
```

the matched string should be `This is my`. What will be the regular expression for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
^([\w ]*) [\w]+$
```

`^` is start of line

`([\w ]*)` is your group of any number of letters and space

`\w+` is a space followed by one or more word characters

`$` is end of line.

Comment: Close, but better would be `^(?:[\w ]*)(?= [\w]+$)` so the match value is good instead for needing to fish it from a group.

Comment: Or simpler still: `^.*(?= [\w]+$)`. And one could allow for ending punctuation with: `^.*(?= [\w]+[.?!]?$)`

Comment: `(.+)(?=\W)`: _everything_ but _last word_

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need regexp for this task, delete everything from the last whitespace to the end of the string and you'll have what you need.

Comment: Agreed if it's that simple, myString.SubString(0, myString.LastIndexOf(" ")) should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd go with something less opaque for such a simple task:

```
var words = Regex.Split("this is my house",@"\s");
var allButLastWord = string.Join(" ",words.Take(words.Length-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

If it ends with a whitespace (as per example), you can define it as:

```
 ^(.*)\s
```

This will remove the whitespace at the end which I believe is desirable effect.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `Split` and do something like this -

```
var text = "This is my house";
var arr = text.Split(' ');
var newtext = String.Join(" ",arr.Take(arr.Length-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string GetAllWordsExceptLast (string original)
{
    original = original.Trim();
    return original.Substring(0, original.LastIndexOf(' '));
}
```

Unless you're really determined to use Regular Expressions. Just seems a little overkill for such a simple operation.

Answer (score 0):

A robust solution trimming leading spaces:

`(?!\s)(.+)(?=\s)`
See it at work on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/AXZiqb/2)

Example: "**5** hours", " **5** hours", "**twenty five** minutes", " **twenty five** minutes"

#### Explanation

- **Negative Lookahead** `(?!\s)`
  *Assert that the Regex below does not match*
  `\s` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)
- **1st Capturing Group** `(.+)`

  - `.+` matches any character (except for line terminators)
  - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- **Positive Lookahead** `(?=\s)`
  *Assert that the Regex below matches*
  `\s` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)